# How to keep EditText from breaking to the next line when width does not match_parent?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to fit two `EditText`s horizontally. What I am trying to accomplish is make the text keep scrolling right without the `EditText` extending in anyway when there is no more space in that specific `EditText`. This happens when the `EditText` is set to `match_parent` (width), but when I set an actually width or `wrap_content`, it breaks to the next line. Not the behavior I am hoping for. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you're saying you want the edit text to be a single line each? If so, have you tried using the xml attribute

```
android:singleLine
```

Or you can accomplish the same thing with:

```
setSingleLine() //called on the edit text
```

I just tested it out with 2 edit texts in a horizontal linear layout set to 100dp width each and I think it accomplishes the behavior you want.

Comment: No, two `EditText`s on the same line, horizontally. Not separate lines.

Comment: Yeah I edited my response to try and reflect that single line still accomplishes the same behavior. I tried it out with two edit texts (with this [http://pastebin.com/YEV5bKg8] layout file) and it kept both EditText widths to half the screen.

Comment: Huh. Do I use `android:singleLine` on each `EditText` or on the containing parent tag, which in my case is a `LinearLayout`?

Comment: Oh idk what happened to the paste. But yeah, you put it in each EditText. Edit: here's the paste http://pastebin.com/YEV5bKg8

Comment: Thanks man. It seemed to work. Also learned about a new attribute. There is one problem. `android:singleLine` is deprecated. I want to use the non-deprecated version, which seems to be `android:inputType`. Main problem is I don't see anything that keeps it on a single line. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show me where it says this is deprecated? I don't see any mention of it in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html. All the same, I think if you set the input type to 'text' the keyboard the pops up when you select it automatically handles that for you and constraints it to single line (if you want multiline text you say the input type is textMultiLine). See at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks a lot. I was actually looking at it through eclipse. If you auto complete `android:` you end up with options and for `android:singleLine` it says deprecated. Check it out. But in either case, you helped me big time! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Set both to `fill_parent` and `layout_weight=1`. This will align them side by side.

Comment: Thats not working. It was a good idea though. Don't know why thats not working. Maybe layout_weight only affects the vertical.